# Does the existence of a specialty site make new questions OT?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic

Since tex.se.com has been launched does that mean `latex` is off topic on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Your title is generic, the question is not. Do you want a generic answer, or a specific one to `latex`?

Comment: On Super User, luckily OS X question are still welcomed, though http://apple.stackexchange.com was introduced too.

Comment: Might I add Ubuntu is on-topic at both [unix.se] and SuperUser, although [ubuntu.se] exists?

Comment: Okay. Let me add then, is this a good thing?

Comment: Yes, I feel that's a good thing. But I might not be objective as I don't like a specific Apple site a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the question.

If the question can legitimately belong to one site (say it is a latex programming question), then it is not off-topic and can remain on it, even if there is a more specialized site for the question.

If, however, it is about some aspect that is not covered by a site (say the question is about typography in tex, asked on Stack Overflow), it is off-topic by nature and should be migrated.

Comment: Yes.  In general, it should be off-topic on the originating site before migration is considered.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Should we then decline flags asking for migration of questions if they are on topic (about TeX layout code) but people say they'd find a better audience at the target site? I've seen a bunch of people comment that the heavy TeX users have moved from SO to TeX.SE, and the people able to answer are mostly located there.

Comment: @BradLarson: I almost always migrate TeX questions. That they are principally about TeX, and peripherally about programming, makes them no less of a good fit over there. I'm thinking more about corner cases [like this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956220/setting-up-a-central-clr-storeproc-function-respository-library-for-internal-sto?noredirect=1)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Tex seems to be special... they also want tex shopping questions :)